# DDoS & Amazon Lightsail Load Balancing

Tags: load-balancing, ddos, amazon-lightsail

One of the sites I host on Amazon Lightsail recently became victim of a DDoS attack. I've been able to fend it off using Cloudflare's "I'm under attack" mode.

I'm wondering if load balancing would have help deal with the attack. Should I create a load balancer in Amazon Lightsail and attach it to all my instances? Is that allowed? Will that help deal with DDoS attacks?

And as for cost - I see it's US$18 monthly. Is that for each instance the load balancer is associated with?

Answer (score 0):

yes it can as it would attempt to distribute the load